# What implies $f_n (y) \leq f(x) + \epsilon$ about $f$ ?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, limits, functions, continuity

Let $X$ be a regular topological space.

**Question:**
For which functions $f : X \rightarrow \mathbb R$, can we find a sequence of functions $f_n : X \rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that:

$\forall \epsilon>0$ and $\forall x \in X$ exists a neighbourhood $O_{\epsilon,x}$ of $x$ and exists a $N_{\epsilon,x} \in \mathbb N$ such that for all $y \in O_{\epsilon,x}$ and $n>N_{\epsilon,x}$
$$
f_n (y) \leq f(x) + \epsilon
$$

**Trivial:**
This is of cause true for all $f$ that are upper semi continuous. Then with $f_n = f$.

But is the set of $f$ that satisfies this condition larger than the upper semicontinuous function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each function $f:X\to\Bbb R$ it suffices to put $f_n\equiv -n$ for each $n$. :-)